# SQLAlchemy: delete single entry from many-to-many table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm probably overthinking this (or underthinking this), but I'm confused about how to delete a single row from a many-to-many table in SQLAlchemy. The docs spend a lot of time talking about cascading deletes, and the examples here also generally have to do with searching for things, or doing multiple rows.

But I want to delete a row *only* from the association table.

Here's my setup. For a restaurant app, I'm mapping dinners to guests. I'm not showing all rows in the "dinner" or "guest" tables.

in models.py:

```
guest_dinner = db.Table('guest_dinner',
                        db.Column('guest_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('guest.id')),
                        db.Column('dinner_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dinner.id')))

class Dinner(db.Model):
    __tablename__='dinner'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)

    guests = db.relationship('Guest',
                             secondary=guest_dinner,
                             back_populates='dinners')

class Guest(db.Model):
    __tablename__='guest'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(256))

    dinners = db.relationship('Dinner',
                              secondary=guest_dinner,
                              back_populates='guests')
```

Then in my view.py:

```
# dinner_id and guest_id are passed as parameters
dinner = Dinner.query.get(dinner_id)
guest = Guest.query.get(guest_id)
if dinner == None or guest == None:
    flash('Record does not exist')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

# WHAT GOES HERE? to delete from association table only
```

That's it. I don't want to delete a dinner or a guest. I want to delete the fact that a guest has attended a specific dinner, i.e. the record in guest_dinner only.